# Cant open data base sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im using flask's sql alchemy and when i try to open the website it gives me this exception

```
OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
return fn()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 320, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)Open an interactive python shell in this frame
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 884, in _checkout
fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 486, in checkout
rec = pool._do_get()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
return self._create_connection()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 266, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 381, in __init__
self.__connect()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __connect
pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
compat.raise_(
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
raise exception
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 673, in __connect
self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
File "c:\Users\Nour\Desktop\Tools\The New Rdimo\clean-test-web\website\views.py", line 10, in home
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2772, in all
return self._iter().all()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2907, in _iter
result = self.session.execute(
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1713, in execute
conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1552, in _connection_for_bind
return self._transaction._connection_for_bind(
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 747, in _connection_for_bind
conn = bind.connect()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3315, in connect
return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
else engine.raw_connection()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
util.raise_(
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
raise exception
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
return fn()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 320, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 884, in _checkout
fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 486, in checkout
rec = pool._do_get()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
return self._create_connection()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 266, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 381, in __init__
self.__connect()
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __connect
pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
compat.raise_(
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
raise exception
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 673, in __connect
self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
File "C:\Users\Nour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

file tree
actual-display
instance
database.db
website
static
main.css
templates
base.html
error.html
**init**.py
models.py
views.py

main.py

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

init.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path


db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hellolol'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)
    
    from .views import views
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    

    
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    
    return app
```

views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from .models import singleRequest
from . import db

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("base.html", query=singleRequest.query.all())
    else:
        
        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        message = request.form.get('message')
        information = [name, email, message]
        for info in information:
            if info == None:
                return render_template("error.html")
            else:
                continue
        
        theRequest = singleRequest(name=name, email=email, message=message)
        db.session.add(theRequest)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("base.html", query=singleRequest.query.all())
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table align="center">
      <caption>Logs</caption>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Message</th>
          </tr>
          
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for info in query %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{info.name}}</td>
              <td>{{info.email}}</td>
              <td>{{info.message}}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="center">
          Made By Omar
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
  </table>
  <br> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#61764B;">
        <h2>Name</h2>
        <ol>
          {% for info in query %}
          <li class="list-group-item">{{info.name}}
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#9BA17B;">
        <h2>Email</h2>
        <ol>
          {% for info in query %}
          <li class="list-group-item">
            {{info.email}}
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#4FA095;">
        <h2>Message</h2>
        <ol>
          {% for info in query %}
          <li class="list-group-item">{{info.message}}
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

error.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Error</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 align="center">Problem occured with submited information</h1>
        <h2 align="center"><a href="https://hidan-on-cord-github-io.vercel.app/">Go back to main page</a></h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <p align="center">Please contact the developer</p>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from . import db
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class singleRequest(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    email = db.Column(db.String(20000))
    name = db.Column(db.String(20000))
    message = db.Column(db.String(20000))
```

i tried it an hour before the error happened and the code was running smoothly now its bugged im guessing i messed up something in the files

Answer (score 0):

it worked magically again pretty sure it was the problem with the hosting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).